# clojure.java.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, clojure, graphviz

I've written a program to assemble .dot files, and want to use Clojure's `sh` to give a compile command. Specifically, I use the following function to do it:

```
(defn compile-graphviz
  "Dumps graphviz-string to a file, then compiles it using dot."
  [graphviz-string]
  (do
    (spit "./tree.dot" graphviz-string)
    (sh "dot -Tpng \"/.tree.dot\" -o\"/.tree.png\"")))
```

However, when I run this, the second part fails, giving the following error message at the REPL:

```
IOException error=2, No such file or directory  java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec (UNIXProcess.java:-2)
```

I've looked at the documentation for `sh` and examples, and I can't understand why this wouldn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.java.shell/sh), `sh` uses execve semantics:

```
(sh "dot" "-Tpng" "/.tree.dot" "-o" "/.tree.png")
```