# Can't run (sh "python hello_world.py") from Clojure repl but python3 hello_world.py works in the shell

Tags: shell, clojure

I have a simple Python file `hello.py` with contents: `print("Hello World")`, and when I try to run this from the REPL using `(sh "python3 hello.py")`, I get

```
Execution error (IOException) at java.lang.UNIXProcess/forkAndExec (UNIXProcess.java:-2).
error=2, No such file or directory
```

Obviously the program runs when I run `python3 hello.py` in the shell. How do I run a Python file from the Clojure repl?

Comment: `clojure.java.shell/sh` doesn't actually start a shell, function and namespace names notwithstanding. Run `(sh "python3" "hello.py")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Pass each `execve()` element (which is to say, each element of the array of strings that's passed to the operating system when actually starting a new process) as a separate argument:

```clj
(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])
(sh "python3" "hello.py")
```

Contrary to what its name may imply, `clojure.java.shell/sh` does not actually invoke `sh`. Instead, it directly calls `Runtime.exec()`, which takes a direct argument list.

If you *wanted* to invoke a shell, you can do that explicitly:

```clj
(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])
(sh "sh" "-c" "python3 hello.py")
```

---

Or, better, make your `hello.py` be an executable with a valid shebang, and invoke it directly. That is to say, make sure `hello.py` starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, run `chmod +x ./hello.py`, and run use:

```clj
(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])
(sh "./hello.py")
```

(Also, consider ditching the `.py` extension; just as you run `pip` instead of `pip.py`, and `ls` instead of `ls.elf`, executable scripts shouldn't have extensions either).

Comment: Following your own advice here, I think it would be better to mark this as a duplicate of something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/56772111/625403 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577521/clojure-java-sh-no-such-file-or-directory, rather than writing another answer for this frequent misunderstanding of how `clojure.java.shell` works.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing those out.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this helper function](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.200/api/tupelo.misc#shell-cmd) for running shell commands

```
(shell-cmd <cmd-str>)
```

> Runs a command string in the default OS shell (/bin/bash); returns
>   result in a Clojure map. Example:

```
(shell-cmd "ls -ldF *")
```

with result:

```
{:exit 0    ; unix exit status (0 -> normal) 
 :err ''    ; text from any errors 
 :out '...' ; text output as would printed to console 
}
```

Try it with a unix command first to help diagnose any PATH issues.

---

### Update

Charles had the right answer.  When you call via `shell/sh` it expects a different string for each argument.  Example:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.misc :as misc]
    [clojure.java.shell :as shell] ))

(dotest
  ; `tupelo.misc/shell-cmd` calls bash first, so space is OK
  (is= (misc/shell-cmd "python3 hello.py")
    {:exit 0, :out "Hello World\n", :err ""})

  ; calls `python3` directly. Need separate string "hello.py"
  (is= (shell/sh "python3" "hello.py")
    {:exit 0, :out "Hello World\n", :err ""})

  ; fails since looking for a single command "python3 hello.py"
  (throws? (shell/sh "python3 hello.py")))
```

Comment: This would only be needed if `python3` were in the current directory.

Comment: ...which is to say, `python3` itself does not use the `PATH` to find the scripts it's told to execute. The OP's "command not found" is because there's no file named `python3 hello.py` **with the space in its name** in their PATH.